# Start Jenkins-Tasks as Pre-Build-Step

Tags: maven, jenkins

is it somehow possible to automatically start 3 of 4 different Jenkins-Jobs (Which build different maven modules) when starting a 4th job? To be precise what I want to achieve:

I want to just start one task which automatically triggers 3 other ones as a "pre build step", so it starts tasks 1-3 and THEN task 4. I can only see a possibility to have tasks build as a POST build step, but not PRE build. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Pre build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PreBuild+Plugin) and then define your workflow accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Create the different jobs 1-4. Then use a [pipeline script](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) and just execute the jobs you want in whatever order you want.

(template copied from the docs linked above)

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('pre-step-1') { 
            steps {
                // call job #1 here
            }
        }
        stage('pre-step-2') { 
            steps {
                // call job #2 here. I skipped 3 cause I'm lazy.
            }
        }
        stage('pre-step-4') { 
            steps {
                // call job #4 here
            }
        }
    }
}
```